# Remove Unwanted Color From 'Transparent' Background in Adobe Photoshop CC 2015

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was using 'Polygonal Lasso Tool' to draw a Black stripe in the uniform of the image (below), accidentally, I colored a small part of the 'Transparent Background' of the image. Now I'm looking for a tool to remove it from the background, because it's looking so bad. I've searched a lot for a working tool or something, but nothing is giving me a better result. So, I want to know - *what's the right tool in order to remove this black area completely from the background?* **(I'm using 'Adobe Photoshop CC 2015')**

[image]

Comment: uhm.. the Eraser Tool?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your workflow. In Photoshop it's best to have everything on individual layers. That's how Photoshop works - it's all about the layers!  So with that in mind try this*.

1. Instead of drawing the stripe on the Jersey cut out layer, add a new layer above it, and draw the black stripe on that new layer, and then make it a layer group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Then, in the layers panel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the jersey cutout layer, this will load it as a selection.
3. Select the layer group, then click the *Add Layer Mask* icon at the bottom of the panel. This will add a layer mask to the group based on the selection.

Now any additional layers you put inside the layer group will be masked to fit the jersey.

*If you can't do this now because you can't undo it, then you will have to use the eraser tool, or make a selection around overlapping part and delete it. In future make sure you use layers instead, so everything will be on individual editable layers so you don't have to fix things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a clipping mask by clicking between two layers while holding alt

[image]